# Is there a function that returns the degree of a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, math-software

I'm playing around with some equations in Geogebra and the degree of the polynomials I am using has become a variable. Is there an exact method for determining the degree of a polynomial?

I am currently approximating the degree of $f(x)$ by using:

$$\text{Degree}(f(x)) = \lfloor\log_{1000}(f(1000))\rfloor$$

This has been a decent enough approximation, but it got me wondering whether or not there exists a precise method? One that could be applied to non-integer degree polynomials.

Comment: What do you mean by order of a polynomial?

Comment: The highest power. I.e. $x^4 + x^3$ is order 4

Comment: Ah I see, in most contexts this is called the degree.

Comment: Now that you've mentioned it that does ring a bell. *Rapidly changes all notation*

Comment: Are you asking whether there is a function in Geogebra or in general?

Comment: Just some food for thought- Making this method more robust would require that the formula needs to take into account the size and sign of the leading term. If the leading coefficient is negative, you can't take the log of it. If it's really large or small, it will throw off the evaluation at $x=$ some big number.

Comment: There's something of an imprecision here. Sure, there's a function like this: $a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \ldots + a_0 \mapsto n$, when we have access to the usual representation of our polynomial as a linear combination of powers of $x$. But really, you're interested in knowing if there's a way to find the degree of a polynomial *when you only have access to the polynomial function's values*, which is a seemingly more subtle problem.

Comment: - Martin, Geogebra for use. General for curiosity.

Comment: - Harry, I guess I could reduce the problem to non-negative leading coefficients. For what I've been doing that will always been the case

Comment: - pjs36 I will be typing in the function, so I do have access to the usual representation. But I think you're right in narrowing the problem. It must be determined from the values outputted by $f(x)$

Comment: Use @username to ping certain people. If you start typing a username, it should suggest you the options where you can select using arrow keys and use tab completion (You're automatically pinged because it's your question).

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think "non integer degree polynomial" is an oxymoron.

Comment: Your proposed expression is wrong, even if the leading coefficient is small and positive: if the second-largest coefficient is negative, you will be off by $1$, because the fractional part will be close to $1$. You can remedy this by using $\lfloor \log_{1000}(f(1000))+\frac12\rfloor$. (But even here, you have to "let $1000$ tend to infinity" to make it work.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to the [GeoGebra wiki](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Degree_Command), the function you're looking for is `Degree[<Polynomial]`. If you have a polynomial in several variables, you can also use `Degree[<Polynomial>,<Variable>]` to get the degree of the polynomial in the specified variable.

Comment: I feel like I should have stumbled upon that. I guess that's what happens when you use the term order instead of degree!

Comment: Well, for next time you know :)

Answer (score 37):

In general, if $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, then
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\log(|f(x)|)}{\log(x)} = n$$

This works because, for large values of $x$, we would have $|f(x)| \approx |a_n| x^n$, where $a_n$ is the leading coefficient, and therefore $\log(|f(x)|) \approx \log(|a_n|) + n\log(x)$.  Divide this by $\log(x)$, and we get $\frac{\log(|f(x)|)}{\log(x)} \approx \frac{\log(|a_n|)}{\log(x)} + n$.  In the limit as $x \to \infty$, the first term goes to $0$.

Moreover, even if $f(x)$ is *not* a polynomial, but (say for example) something like $f(x) = x^{1/2} - 3x^{1/3}$, this method works, in that it returns the largest non-negative exponent among the terms; in this case, we get $1/2$.

Comment: This is how I arrived at my approximation. Since I can't use limits in geogebra I think I'm just going to have to work with my approximation. If you know of any alternatives please let me know!

Comment: @BenCrossley-hobbyist, why can you not use limits in GeoGebra? `LimitBelow[log(abs(f(x)))/log(x), ∞]` seems to work just fine.

Comment: Because I was unaware that putting $\infty$ was valid! I've learned some great stuff in this question!

Comment: This is essentially taking the logarithm base $x$.